# How to return drupal error message in php cli

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

I am programmatically saving nodes with corresponding photos into a D7 content type.  It's working well sometimes, and failing on others, and I am sure it has something to do with a form field not having the right data.

Typically this would throw an error when manually uploading via the Drupal content type form, but I am using the PHP CLI.  How can I output that message to the CLI?

I tried 'print $messages' which is what is used for web pages, but, alas, that is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the command line, have a look at PHP's [input/output streams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php). These let you write data out to where your environment would be expecting to receive output.

Alternatively, you might want a look at Drupal's built-in logging with [watchdog()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7). You can see the messages it generates in Administration >> Reports >> Recent log messages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the method you are using to save the nodes. If you are using [drupal_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7), then you can get the errors by calling [form_get_errors()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7).

Comment: I am using node_submit($node) then calling node_save($node), if that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you would use [`drupal_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7), this should work:

```
if (drupal_is_cli() && $errors = form_get_errors()) {
  print_r($errors);
}
```

However when using `node_submit()` and `node_save()`, I believe it's bypassing the validation rules.

Otherwise you can do something like that:

```
// ...
node_save($node); // After this call we'll get a nid.
if (!$node->nid && drupal_is_cli()) {
  drush_print(sprintf("Failed to create a node: %s of type: %s.", $node->title, $node->type));
}
```

or check out the following one-liner:

```
$node->nid ?: drupal_is_cli() && printf("Failed to create a node: %s of type: %s.\n", $node->title, $node->type);
```

Eventually you may try to print the error messages via:

```
print_r(drupal_get_messages());
```